# It "would have been" or "would be" in this sentence

Tags: conditionals

I saw the question in English textbook. There is "Sorry we're late. our taxi got stuck in the traffic. **It would have been** quicker if we had walked." I think the answer is **would be** not **would have been** because it refer to present which is **We are late**. Would someone please answer is?

I'm looking forward to get some advises.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**would have been** is correct. The structure **would have been...if...had...** is used to describe the situation where something has happened, but you wish it could've been done differently. **would be...if...** on the other hand, is used to describe something that hasn't happened but you expect it to happen.

Examples:

> He would have lived if we had known about his disease.
>
> I could have gotten into that university if I had studied hard.
>
> It seems that there is a traffic jam. It would be faster if we take the subway.

---

Also, in your sentence **would have been** does not refer to the present, it refers to the past, which is whether we took the taxi or walked. What would have been quicker? Walking, which is what we should have done **in the past**.